# How to animate a 3D character?

Tags: 3d, blender, collada

I have some 3D character model, and I would like to animate them, to use them in my project. The result should be a keyframe animated collada.
I need only the basic movements: walk, run, aim, die...

Are there any programs for that? I unfortunatly can't really use Blender or 3D studio max.
I don't know, where else can I ask it, so I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others said before you will have to learn at least some basic concepts of 3D and the modelling tool of your choice. There is one site I have worked with, the [Mixamo Auto Rigger](http://www.mixamo.com/c/automatic-rigging-for-blender-unity3d?utm_source=unity_blog). There you can upload your character and they apply some automatic rigging algorithm out of the vertices if and only if your character is humanoid, cows, dogs, .. have to stay outside

Using this rig you can attach some basic animation from their store (some of them are for free) and download it as collada file for using it in Blender if you use their own collada importer. I did this once spent a few € and finally got it working.

So far it seems like what you are looking for, but:

- The rig was really heavy in that it contained bones for every finger and toe
- The names of the bones were not very expressive
- A year ago their collada importer just worked on Blender 2.4.9
- Getting this done requires you to know the basics of working in Blender otherwise you don't have a chance.

Answer (score 3):

- What format is your model in?
- Is it already [rigged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation) for animation (does it have a skeleton and the correct vertex-weighting)?

Whatever your answer - you will NEED to use a 3D model/animation editor and then export it using the correct COLLADA exporter. Unless you're thinking of getting someone else to do the animation for you (in which case this isn't a relevant question for these forums) I'm afraid you have no other option.

Comment: I have no bones or something like. But I hope there is an application for creating animated models easy.

Comment: Sorry - this isn't the right forum to ask for open suggestions, leave alone non-programming related suggestions. I would recommend you move it to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ Oh, and BTW you will need to understand some basic 3D concepts and perform those tasks by yourself. There is nothing like an "easy" tool to create animated models.

Comment: [Character Shop](http://www.thegamecreators.com/?m=view_product&id=2094) is an easy tool with some built-in movements. But it can only export .x file for Darkbasic Pro, and it loads models sometimes wrong, beacuse it's an old software